# How can DE's like Gnome detect that a Tkinter Window is related to a .desktop entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Python Script that creates a simple Hello World Window using Tkinter.

When i create a .desktop Entry for the Script and save it in `~/.local/share/applications`, It shows up like a normal Application in Gnome "App Drawer". However when I pin it to the Dash, and launch it, it does not detect that the Window relates to the Programm and Creates a new icon in the Taskbar. How can I achieve that the new Window of my Script is "Attached" to the .dektop Entry

My Desktop Entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Test
Exec=/home/pauljako/boundaries/Code/test/main.py
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=boundaries;
StartupNotify=true;
```